# Update a post's taxonomy when a specific acf_form() is updated

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, advanced-custom-fields

I'm currently building a parent admissions portal for a school. Pupils are created as a custom post type (`pupil`) when a user (parent) signs up – the parent is the author of each `pupil` post. These `pupil` posts have a custom taxonomy named `status` which determines if the pupil's admission forms have been submitted and reviewed. I'm using `acf_form()` to create the admission forms that display on the frontend and are filled in by the parent user. Each pupil currently has 6 ACF field groups (6 forms). I'm getting the keys of these field groups and looping through them with a `foreach` loop to display 6 individual `acf_form()` forms for each of the field groups.

When a `pupil` post is created, it's `status` is automatically set to "in progress" i.e. the parent is filling out the forms.

**What I want**

When a user updates one specific form/field group of the 6, I want the pupil's `status` taxonomy to be changed from "in progress" to "submitted". To explain further, this form is the final form the user/parent needs to complete and so once they press the `acf_form()` update button, the taxonomy should be updated.

**So essentially...**

I'm looking for a way to hook into the action of saving an `acf_form()`, doing a check to see if the form that was updated was a specific form (by the field group key?) and then updating the `status` taxonomy of the post that the form was submitted on.

**What I've tried**

I've tried using ACF's `pre_save_post` filter and `save_post` action but I can't figure out a way to check which field group was saved as those two functions just give me the `$post_id`. I simply added the code from the [ACF Docs](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/acf-save_post/) and tried to `print_r()` / `echo` the data from the functions to see if there was any way for me to check the field group key, but nothing is being printed on the page when I update the `acf_form()`.

**So...**

Does anyone know how I can hook into that action properly and get the correct data that will allow me to do the checks that I want?

Comment: Your description is a bit confusing, I am not sure which form you are actually submitting here now. That you use “form/field group” as if they were the same thing, isn’t helping either.

Comment: @04FS Sorry, form and field group are the same things in my case as I'm running `acf_form()` for each field group by running a `foreach` on an array of field group keys and passing the field group key into `acf_form()` each time. So basically I have a page with 6 `acf_form()` on it and you can submit/save each one individually.

Comment: So are these different forms (with different fields) for one and the same pupil? Or are they six identical forms, for six different pupils?

Comment: @04FS Yes, 6 different field groups for each/every pupil post that have their own fields, so on the pupil single page there are 6 separate forms that have different fields

Comment: @04FS I've found a way to do it but I don't think it's a very good or robust way, I'm going to post it as an answer so you and others can see but I would still appreciate your help if you know of a better way

Comment: Hm, I guess ACF is not really prepared for such a scenario. Might perhaps make more sense to try and handle this in the update filter for the specific field you want to base this on? https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/acf-update_value/

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do what I'm looking for but I feel like it isn't a very good or robust way to do it so I'm still open to suggestions/advice.

**The code:**

```
function my_acf_save_post( $post_id ) {

    $keys_of_specific_field_group = array(
        'field_5ce2970bc9fbd' => '',
        'field_5ce29741c9fbe' => '',
        'field_5ce297c7c9fc1' => '',
        'field_5ce297ddc9fc2' => '',
        'field_5ce297fac9fc3' => '',
        'field_5ce2980ec9fc4' => '',
        'field_5ce29874c9fc5' => '',
        '_validate_email' => ''
    );

    if ( $_POST['acf'] === $keys_of_specific_field_group ) {

        wp_set_post_terms($post_id, array(21), 'status');

    }

}

add_action('acf/save_post', 'my_acf_save_post', 1);
```

Basically I am just checking if the field keys returned from `$_POST['acf']` match the field keys of the fields in the specific form I want to check, and if they do I am updating the post's `status taxonomy` (`array(21)` is the ID of the 'submitted' term I want to set).

Hopefully there's a nicer/better way to do this as if any fields are added to the field group I will have to manually update the code.